# elisp macro to write a function?

Tags: emacs, function, macros, elisp

I have written a few nearly identical functions, except for their names.  For example:

```
; x is name, such as function/paragraph/line/etc.
(defun my-x-function
 (interactive)
 (mark-x) (do-more-stuff) (modify-x))
```

Is there a way to automatically generate such functions? I have a feeling this is what macros do, but I am not sure how to use them. Any help, maybe including a small example would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yep, that's exactly what macros do.  Here's a straightforward macro that builds functions according to the pattern you specified:

```
(defmacro make-my-function (name)
  (list 'defun (intern (format "my-%s-function" name)) ()
        (list 'interactive)
        (list (intern (format "mark-%s" name)))
        (list 'do-more-stuff)
        (list (intern (format "modify-%s" name)))))
```

You can copy this macro to a `*scratch*` buffer in Emacs and evaluate it, and then check that it works like this:

```
(make-my-function x) ; type control-J here
my-x-function ; <-- Emacs's output
(symbol-function 'my-x-function) ; type control-J here
(lambda nil (interactive) (mark-x) (do-more-stuff) (modify-x)) ; <-- Emacs's output
```

More commonly one would use the [backquote](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) facility to write macros more concisely, but all macros essentially work in the same manner as the above example.

Answer (score 3):

Macros can do that, but there are lots of template modules for emacs to do similar work.  I use a thing called [yasnippet.el](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yasnippet) to do quick code-generation things.  For example, in a C-source file, if I type `for<TAB>`, I get a for loop template; it allows me to fill in the template, setting the variable name, limits, and internal loop contents.

looks like this:

[image]

You can set up templates for anything you like.  Function definitions, if statements, switch statements, whatever. Set up different templates for different modes.  The template for a `for` loop in C is different than the template for a `for` loop in C#, and so on. Very handy.

Comment: yasnippet is great, but might not necessarily be the same thing.  Macro is ambiguous, because emacs has *keyboard macros* which replicate typing or *lisp macros* which alter the code tree; yasnippet is more helpful mainly if he has to enter a set of boilerplate that can't be abstracted out (which is more true of C/C++ than Lisp.)