# Use a string variable as macro argument

Tags: emacs, lisp-macros

I want this code :

```
(setq name "foobar")
(defun (intern name) ())
```

do the same thing as :

```
(defun foobar ())
```

I have tried this (from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437254/elisp-macro-to-write-function)):

```
(defmacro make-my-function (name)
(list 'defun
(intern (format "my-%s-function" name)) ()
    (list 'interactive)
    '(message "It's work !")))
```

But I get a function called my-name-function but I want my-foobar-function. My goal is to define minors modes from an alist of keymap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your issue with your `make-my-function` macro, but try it with the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html):

```
(defmacro make-my-function (name)
  `(defun ,(intern (format "my-%s-function" name)) ()
    'interactive
    '(message "It works!")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your macro works fine. How did you try to invoke it? You should invoke like this: `(make-my-function foo)`.  Then `M-: (symbol-function 'my-foo-function)` shows you the function definition:

```
(lambda nil
  (interactive)
  (message "It's work !"))
```

The reason that your initial attempt, before defining the macro, did not work is that `defun` is a macro - it does not evaluate its arguments. So `(defun (intern name) ())` is syntactically incorrect: `defun` needs a symbol as its first argument, and `(intern name)` is a list, not a symbol.

---

Updated, after your comment -

Your question is quite UNclear.  Now it sounds like you want to call `(make-my-function foo)` in a context where you have a *variable* `my-foo-function`, whose value is a string.

If that's the case then use this:

```
(defmacro make-my-function (name)
  (list 'defun
        (intern (symbol-value (intern (format "my-%s-function" name))))
        ()
        (list 'interactive)
        '(message "It's work !")))

(setq my-foo-function "toto")
(make-my-function foo)
```

I cannot imagine such a use case, but I suspect that this too is not what you are trying to do.  It does not seem like you have specified well what the required behavior is.

Comment: I think you misunderstand : I want to invoke my macro like this : (make-my-function a-variable-contain-the-name-as-string) and not like this : (make-my-function foobar)

Comment: My main problem is to convert a string to symbol

Comment: A macro does not evaluate its arguments, unless you tell it to. If you want `(make-my-function a-variable-contain-the-name-as-string)` to evaluate `a-variable-contain-the-name-as-string` then the macro body needs to explicitly evaluate that argument.